# How to run service not as root

Tags: linux, services, systemd, privileges

I created successfully a service on my Linux RedHat by copy the Unit-File to `/usr/lib/systemd/system/mediation.service`

I can successfully start/stop/enable/... the service with

```
systemctl enable mediation
systemctl start mediation
etc.
```

However, since `systemctl` is usually executed by root, my application runs also as root. How can I configure the service that it runs under a different (non-privileged) user?

Comment: What if you separately add the commands to the sudoers file of the non-root user you want to run as?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
User=myuser
```

In your unit file.

This is documented in [man systemd.exec](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#User=)

Also, custom files should not go in `/usr/lib/systemd/system`, they should go in `/etc/systemd/system`. The former is where packages install their files. The later is where system administrators should put their files.